# WPF Control moves but its Adorner - Not :"/

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, adorner

I created an adorner on a WPF line element, because there was neet to add some text.

Now, when this line is moved, the adorner does not "follow" the line automatically. In fact, it does not refresh itsef:

[image] [image]
here black curves is the Control drawing, and the red "120 m" is the adorner one.

Some code

```
    void SegmentLine_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AdornerLayer aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        if (aLayer != null)
        {
            aLayer.Add(new TextAdorner(this));
        }
    }

    class TextAdorner : Adorner
    {
        public TextAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
            : base(adornedElement)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            SegmentLine segment = (this.AdornedElement as SegmentLine);

            if (segment != null)
            {
                Rect segmentBounds = new Rect(segment.DesiredSize);
                var midPoint = new Point(
                    (segment.X1 + segment.X2) / 2.0, 
                    (segment.Y1 + segment.Y2) / 2.0);
                var lineFont = // get line font as Font

                FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(
                    string.Format("{0} m", segment.Distance),
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                    System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                    new Typeface(lineFont.FontFamily.ToString()),
                    ligneFont.Size, Brushes.Red);

                drawingContext.DrawText(ft, midPoint);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

**Why MeasureOverride, etc aren't being called**

Your adorner's `MeasureOverride`, `ArrangeOverride`, and `OnRender` aren't being called because your SegmentLine control is never changing size or position:

- Since your SegmentLine doesn't implement `MeasureOverride`, it always has the default size assigned by the layout engine.
- Since your SegmentLine doesn't implement `ArrangeOverride` or manipulate any transforms, its position is always exactly the upper-left corner of the container.

The Adorner's `MeasureOverride`, `ArrangeOverride` and `OnRender` are only called by WPF under these conditions:

1. The `AdornedElement` changes size or position (this the most common case), or
2. One of the *Adorner*'s properties chagnes and that property is marked `AffectsMeasure`, `AffectsArrange`, or `AffectsRender`, or
3. You call `InvalidateMeasure()`, `InvalidateArrange()`, or `InvalidateVisuaul()` on the adorner.

Because your SegmentLine never changes size or position, case 1 doesn't apply.  Since you don't have any such properties on the Adorner and don't call `InvalidateMeasure()`, `InvalidateArrange()` or `InvalidateVisual()`, the other cases don't apply either.

**Precise rules for Adorner re-measure**

Here are the precise rules for when an adorned element change triggers a call to `Adorner.MeasureOverride`:

1. The adorned element must force a layout pass by invalidating its `Measure` or `Arrange` in response to some event.  This could be triggered automatically by a change to a DependencyProperty with `AffectsMeasure` or `AffectsArrange`, or by a direct call to `InvalidateMeasure()`, `InvalidateArrange()` or `InvalidateVisual()`.
2. The adorned element's `Measure` and `Arrange` methods must not be called directly from user code between the invalidation and the layout pass.  In other words, you must wait for the layout manager to do the job.
3. The adorned element must make a non-trivial change to either its `RenderSize` or its `Transform`.
4. The combination of all transforms between the `AdornerLayer` and the adorned element must be affine.  This will generally be the case as long as you are not using 3D.

Your SegmentLine is just drawing the line in a new place rather than updating its own dimensions, thereby omitting my requirement #3 above.

**Recommendation**

Normally I would recommend your adorner have AffectsRender DependencyProperties bound to the SegmentLine's properties, so any time X1, Y1, etc change in the SegmentLine they are also updated in the Adorner which causes the Adorner to re-render.  This provides a very clean interface, since the adorner can be used on any control that has properties X1, Y1, etc, but it is less efficient than tightly coupling them.

In your case the adorner is clearly tightly bound to your SegmentLine, so I think it makes just as much sense to call `InvalidateVisual()` on the adorner from the SegmentLine's `OnRender()`, like this:

```
public class SegmentLine : Shape
{
  TextAdorner adorner;

  ...

  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) 
  { 
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    if(adorner==null)
    {
      var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this); if(layer==null) return;
      adorner = new TextAdorner(this);
      ... set other adorner properties and events ...
      layer.Add(adorner);
    }
    adorner.InvalidateVisual();
  } 
}
```

Note that this doesn't deal with the situation where the SegmentLine is removed from the visual tree and then added again later.  Your original code doesn't deal with this either, so I avoided the complexity of dealing with that case.  If you need that to work, do this instead:

```
public class SegmentLine : Shape
{
  AdornerLayer lastLayer;
  TextAdorner adorner;

  ...

  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) 
  { 
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
    if(layer!=lastLayer)
    {
      if(adorner==null)
      {
        adorner = new TextAdorner(this);
        ... set other adorner properties and events ...
      }
      if(lastLayer!=null) lastLayer.Remove(adorner);
      if(layer!=null) layer.Add(adorner);
      lastLayer = layer;
    }
    adorner.InvalidateVisual();
  } 
}
```

Comment: did you see my answer? where should I call Adorner.MeasureOverride? shoudl I override this method in my custom Adorner? thanks.

Comment: see the class details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214435/adorner-and-events-on-adorned-element

Comment: Thanks for posting the class details.  I've updated my answer.  No, you should not call or implement Adorner.MeasureOverride.  See the last section of this updated answer for what you should do.

Comment: One more note:  I noticed you used the Loaded event.  Are you aware that this event only fires when a PresentationSource is connected?  When using Loaded, your Adorner would be missing in certain use cases, such as printing and imaging.  It is better to design WPF controls to ignore Loaded and instead do such tasks in their first MeasureOverride (or ArrangeOverride or OnRender).  That way your controls will work reliably whether or not a PresentationSource is connected.  All the built-in WPF controls do it that way.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Now, a question will be why the adorner does not intercept the events and redirects it to the segmentLine, and I shoudl manually attach them, like you mentioned "... set other adorner properties and events ..."

Comment: Now, I have another problem... When I HitTest, adorner is like not part of the hitTestResults.

Comment: The reference Visual you pass into VisualTreeHelper.HitTest must be higher in your visual tree than your AdornerLayer.

Answer (score 0):

How is the line being moved? Does the MeasureOverride or ArrangeOverride of the adorner get invoked after the move? OnRender will only get invoked if the visual is invalidated (e.g. invalidatevisual) so I'm guessing that the render isn't being invalidated.

Comment: nothing is invoked after the move. If I should invalidate the canvas every time I move the line, I'll leave the adorner approach, because I came back to GDI+ graphics, and I really hoped that WPF will not impose me to refresh the screen each time I make a move.

Comment: @serhio: Rest assured that WPF is easily capable of moving just the adorner without a full redraw. A bug in your code is preventing the OnRender call from happening. I added an answer that explains what is required for your OnRender to be called.

Comment: I added some class details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214435/adorner-and-events-on-adorned-element

Answer (score 0):

May be you wanted to use `segmentBounds` to define `midPoint`? Otherwise what is it doing there? Looks like you are defining `midPoint` relative to not *rerendered* segment.

Comment: the problem is that when I move the line the code *does even not enter in the OnRender()* adorner method.

Answer (score 0):

idiot fix, but it works

```
    AdornerLayer aLayer;
    void SegmentLine_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        if (aLayer != null)
        {
            aLayer.Add(new TextAdorner(this));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        if (aLayer != null)
        {
            aLayer.Update();
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem is that when I click on a the adorner the control itself does not recieve the hit...

Comment: It works but it is slow if you have thousands of lines on a layer and you've only moved one.

Comment: See my answer for a full explanation of what is going wrong and a more efficient fix.